# Google Map V2 Lib Android, draw active path from GPS update

Tags: android, gps, google-maps-android-api-2

I don't want to show the route as there is no destination point in our app, so what we want is to show the active path of the user over the map from the starting point to the current point.

Problem: As some time or most of the time the location shown outside the road on which user is traveling, which draws the path outside the roads.

Help me to draw the path on the road as user is driving on the road.
How Google do the same? or is there a way to do so which i am missing or 
any algo to correct the path.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very common problem that all GPS devices need to solve.
See http://econym.org.uk/gmap/snap.htm for some examples to snap your location coordinates to a street.